# Rails app with Airbrake - 401 unauthroized

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, airbrake

I am successfully using airbrake in my ruby on rails app with one exception.

On visiting a specific view, I am occasionally getting a 401 unauthorized error:

`POST https://api.airbrake.io/api/v3/projects/0/notices?key= 401 (Unauthorized)`
`api.airbrake.io/api/v3/projects/0/notices?key=:1`

The key appears to be missing however it is only missing sometimes..

I am setting my airbrake credentials in my `app.js` file as follows:

```
// Airbrake project creds
// projectId, projectKey
Airbrake.setProject(projID, projKey);

window.onerror = function(message, file, line) {
  Airbrake.push({error: {message: message, fileName: file, lineNumber: line}});
}
```

Why might this fail sometimes but work other times on one specific view?

Answer (score 1):

You see that error because `Airbrake.setProject` is not called in time or `projID, projKey` are undefined. But I can't say why without seeing full `app.js` contents and knowing how you load that file.

BTW you can find more robust `onerror` handler [here](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js/blob/master/src/instrumentation/onerror.coffee#L1).

Also I recommend you to open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js/issues/new) when you have airbrake-js specific questions.